# Would denormalizing my database in this particular way help performance?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, denormalization

In the site I am currently working on members can favorite other members. Then when a member goes to their favorites page they can see all the members they have favorited throughout time.

I can go about this in 2 ways:

**Method #1:**

Every time a user favorites another I enter a row in the `favorites` table which looks like this (the index is `user_favoriting_id`):

```
id | user_favorited_id | user_favoriting_id
-------------------------------------------
```

Then when they load the "My Favorites" page, I do a select on the favorites table to find all the rows where the user_favoriting_id value equals to that of the present logged in user. I then take the user_favorited_ids to build out a single SELECT statement and look up the respective users from a separate users table.

**Method #2:**

Each time a user favorites another I will update the favorites field on their row in the users table, which looks something like this (albeit with more fields, the index is id):

```
id | username | password | email | account_status | timestamp | favorites
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I will CONCAT the id of the user being favorited in the `favorites` field so that column will hold a comma separated string like so:

`10,44,67` etc...

Then to produce the My Favorites page like method #1 I will just grab all the favorite users with one select. That part is the same.

I know method #1 is the normalized way to do it and is much prettier. But my concern for this particular project is scalability and performance above anything else.

If I choose method #2, it will reduce having to look up on the separate favorites table, since the users table will have to be selected anyway as soon as the user logs in.

And I'm pretty sure using php's explode function to split up those CSV values in method #2 wouldn't take nearly as much time as method #1's additional db look up on the `favorites` table, but just in case I must ask:

From a purely performance perspective, which of these methods is more optimized?

Also please assume that this website will get a trillion page views a day.

Comment: Doing the lookup in method 2 is going to be very slow (you have to parse out each ID and look it up individually), and you can't do ordinary joins against it, so any kind of reporting is probably out.  So you just want to display the ID's, and not a meaningful description for the favorites?

Comment: Agree with @Robert; but add to that it becomes difficult to see 'who is favoriting me?'

Comment: @Robert Harvey actually I was thinking about building out a string like `WHERE id = $split_value` and place it inside the foreach loop where I am running through the exploded CSV array. That way I can append this to the end of the SELECT sql I was going to build anyway. This way the SQL is build out in the php and is one query before it is executed.

Comment: I'd go with the first method.  It's more straightforward, it's faster, it's better practice, and it's relatively straightforward to build the CSV list of ID's if you still need that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that scalability is a concern. This seems to imply that Method #2 won't work for you, because that limits the number of favorites that a user can have. (For example, if you have a million users, then most users will have five-digit IDs. How wide do you want to let `favorites` be? If it's a `VARCHAR(1000)`, that means that fewer than 200 favorites are allowed.)

Also, do you really expect that you will *never* want to know which users have "favorited" a given user? Your Method #2 might be O.K. if you know that you will *always* look up favoritings by "favoriter" rather than "favoritee", but it falls apart completely otherwise. (And even here, it only makes sense if you don't expect to lookup anything meaningful about the "favoritee" aside from his/her user-ID; otherwise, if you actually lookup the "favoritees", then you're basically doing all the hard work of a JOIN, just removing any opportunity for MySQL to do the JOIN intelligently.)

Overall, it's better to start out with best-practices, such as normalization, and to move away from them only when performance requires it. Otherwise something that seems like a performance optimization can have negative consequences, forcing you to write very *un*-optimal code further down the line.

Answer (score 1):

JOINs take time, but I wouldn't make the change until you have some data that suggests that it's necessary.

Normalization is good for a number of reasons; it's not just an academic exercise.

Concatenation of IDs into a column is a heinous crime against normalization.  Don't do it.

You're assuming that your code is faster than all the work that's been done to optimize relational databases.  That's a big mistake.

Make sure that you have indexes on primary and foreign keys that participate in the JOINs.

Profile your app when you have real performance issues; don't guess.

Make sure that the real problem isn't your app.  Bringing back too much unnecessary information will be more of a performance drag than a normalized schema.

Answer (score 0):

Use Both, One (the normalized approach), is preferable from a data normalization, maintainability, and data integrity perspective, (and for other reasons as well) - you should always strongly favor  this approach.

But there's no reason not to use the other approach as well if the normalized approach is not acceptable for read performance.  Often an alternative, denormalized approach will be better for read performance.  So, use the first one as the "master" for keeping track of the data and for ensuring data integrity, and then keep a denormalized "copy" of the data in the other structure for read access... Update the copy from the master any time it changes, (inserts updates, deletes).

But ***measure*** the performance of your alternative approach to ensure it is indeed faster, and by a margin sufficient to justify its use.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know using dernomalization in mysql is really trivial. but if you'd be using something like not a RDBMS but db like couchdb or mongoDB there's the whole engine how to manipulate data in a safe way. And it's **really** scalable, non relational database will work for you **really** faster..

The only method which a prefer for optimizing webapp which uses mysql for example, is to dernomalize table and then give some job to php, and ofcourse using HipHop you will get some really big optimization in there, because you offloaded mysql and loaded php which with HipHop will be optimized up to 50%!

Answer (score 0):

Probably not, but it would totally screw your database up for reasons that others have already cited.

Do NOT use a comma-separated-list-of-IDs pattern. It just sucks.

I strongly suspect that you won't have enough users on your site for this to matter, as unless you're Facebook you are unlikely to have > 1M users. Most of those 1M users won't choose anybody as their favourite (because most will be casual users who don't use that feature).

So you're looking at an extremely small table (say, 1M rows maximum if your 1M users have an average of 1 favourite, although most don't use the feature at all) with only two columns. You can potentially improve the scans in innodb by making the primary key start with the thing that you most commonly want to search by, BUT - get this - you can still add a secondary index on the other one, and get reasonable lookup times (actually, VERY quick as the table will fit into memory on the tiniest server!)